# Insert Combobox items to database column

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

Is it possible to insert values from `combobox` to specific column in database?

For example if i have `combobox` with items: **item1**, **item2**, **item3** and I want to `bind` them to some `column`: **column1**, what I want to manage is this: if **item1** is selected, when I click on `button`, I want to insert value of that item in the **column1**, otherwise if selected item is **item2** then I want value of **item2** to be inserted in **column1**, etc...

Now I know that the question is not really well written, but I just want to know if this is possible to do.

I've been Googling for this type of problem but I couldn't find the solution. I know how to make `column` records to be inserted into `combobox` items list but don't know the way to do the opposite.

Also would like to say that I have this problem in my WPF/WCF/MVVM application, so I would like to know if this is possible (and how) to solve it that way.

Comment: Just clarifying your question, you have two controls on the form, one is combobox and other is button. You want to save the selected value in combobox to database tables's col1 field. is my understanding correct???

Comment: Yes that's right. Let me be more specific: imagine that i have combobox with persons names: George, James, Michael. And have a button insert, and some table in database that have column "Names" which is empty. If i select "Michael" in combobox list, press the button insert, than i want "Michael" to be inserted in column "Names".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution is based on MVVM pattern .
Bind the Selected item of combo box control to some property in View model.
So your view should look like

```
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedItemBinding,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" />

    <Button Command={Binding ButtonClickCommand} ..../>
```

so once the Button is clicked you will get the RelayCommand handle in viewmodel and you can have a logic there to Get the selected item and use the value to insert into the column. Your view model should look like ,

```
    public class ViewModel : //implement notify property changed and ICommand
    {
        public RelayCommand ButtonClickCommand
        {
             get new RelayCommand(EventHandlerToBeCalled);
        }


        public string SelectedItemBinding
        {
             get;
             set
             {
                  //notify property changed.
             }
        }

        //method called when button is clicked.
        private void EventHandlerToBeCalled()
        {
              //here set the SelectedItemBinding to a column.
        }
    }
```

Comment: What if you want to write it to (for example a database) without the use of a button? (so change the combobox value => directly write to the database) with MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

ofc you can. On the button click event you can just get the selected value of the combobox and save it.

```
var selectedItem = ComboBoxName.SelectedItem;
```

But if you have binded the combobox with objects then you can cast it.

```
var selectedItem = ComboBoxName.SelectedItem as (objecttypehere)
```

**Update**
I missed that you used MVVM. Then in the view you can use bind the combobox with selected item.

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectedItem="{Binding TheSelectedItem}">
     //Itemtemplates.       
</ComboBox>
```

In the viewModel just acces the property you binded with the selecteditem in my test case "TheSelectedItem" property.

Save it!

Answer (score 0):

1. in combobox you can store values with prefix (col1_12, col2_24 etc)
2. on button click you should parse value: separate it on prefix and original value
3. so you can write value to needed column:

   switch (prefix) {
   case "col1" : table.column1 = value; break;
   case "col2" : table.column2 = value; break;
   // etc
   }